# Repair Windows Network Configuration (Registry)

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, windows-registry, network-adapter

I have a problem with my windows network configurations and adapters. I have a Realtek LAN port located on the motherboard and a network card for WLAN and Bluetooth from Intel. Due to replacement etc. in the last few years everything has become very messed up (Especially Hyper-V has created a lot of mess).

I would now like to reset all drivers, network adapters, configurations to factory settings, so that I can then reinstall all devices.

The option "reset network" in the settings shows no effect at all.

Current problems:

- In the device manager network adapters are shown with #2 [1].
- In network connections, Ethernet 3 and WLAN 2 are displayed and cannot be renamed to Ethernet or WLAN because an adapter already exists (I don't know where). [2]
- Although a WLAN network connection exists, I cannot connect to a network because the WLAN option is not shown in the Internet Access menu. [3] (This is especially strange because it worked a few months ago).

Well, as I said, I would like to reset everything to factory settings. I imagine that I uninstall all adapters and then delete all keys that have anything to do with the adapters in the registry.
Unfortunately I have no idea if this is possible without destroying Windows and where these keys are located.

I have already found over 6 locations in the registry that have anything to do with the connections/adapters.

I hope someone knows about the Windows network and can help me, because I can't see through it anymore.

Pictures:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnclx.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wglhk.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxAzr.png

Comment: You normally cannot run a computer by changing registry keys.  Assuming Windows 10, run a Widows 10 Repair Install and start with the option to Keep Everything.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Your not even using the Realtek adapter in your screenshots, but you have several virtual adapters, due to software being installed. If your going to provide non-English screenshots like your last screenshot you need to provide an English translation